# How to change Position of Datepicker popup in angular

Tags: html, angular, datepicker, popup

Date picker popup needs to be on the side of calendar dropdown instead of left side

[image: 1]

Date picker popup needs to be towards the datepicker button..i.e right side instead of left.

Answer (score 1):

make in calender tag -> appendTo="body"

Comment: I am using <mat-datepicker-toggle>. its not working in that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

View file:

```
<div class="class-name">
      <input datepicker-popup="...">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class-name{
  position: relative;
}
.class-name.dropdown-menu {
   left: auto !important;
   right: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: I am using <mat-datepicker-toggle>. How can i add condtional css class.

Comment: try to put [touchUi]="true" on the tag mat-datepicker-toggle. It should work!

Comment: Tried it but it is opening the date pivker popup in the center of tha page.

Comment: <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1">
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

Comment: copy this code and paste in your file.

Comment: same i have also written but it is opening the popup on left side. i was also trying with ...xPosition: DatepickerDropdownPositionX but note sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out we can use the following code in your .ts file which have values `start` and `end`

```
@Input() xPosition: DatepickerDropdownPositionX;
```

And in the html file we can make changes as

```
<mat-datepicker #any_id [xPosition]= "xPosition"></mat-datepicker>.
```